# C++ practice exam on Destructors, Copy Constructors, and Assignment Operators

Tags: c++, destructor, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

This is a problem on a practice exam for my midterm in a CS lower div course tomorrow. Unfortunately, the practice exam doesn't have fully correct solutions; the specific problem shown in this question posted received half credit for each of parts a), b), and c).

The question is why they received only half-credit; if you can post a full solution to one or all of the parts of the question, that would be of tremendous value.

The question is below:

---

Consider this excerpt from a rather ordinary class representing a construction worker.

```
class Worker
{
  public:
    Worker(string nm, string s)
        : m_name(nm), m_skill(s)
    {}
    string name() const { return m_name; }
    string skill() const { return m_skill; }
  private:
    string m_name;
    string m_skill;
};
```

Because we did not declare a destructor, copy constructor, or assignment operator for the Worker class, the compiler writes these functions for us.

A construction crew is a collection of workers. We choose to represent a crew as a dynamically allocated array of pointers to Workers. Here is an excerpt:

```
class Crew
{
  public:
    Crew(int lim)
        : m_size(0), m_maxCrewSize(lim)
    {
        m_crew = new Worker*[lim];
    }

    void hire(string nm, string s)
    {
        if (m_size < m_maxCrewSize)
        {
            m_crew[m_size] = new Worker(nm, s);
            m_size++;
        }
    }
    // other functions not shown
  private:
    Worker** m_crew;
    int m_size;
    int m_maxCrewSize;
};
```

The first m_size elements of the m_crew array contain pointers to dynamically allocated workers; the remaining elements have no particular value.

The users of the Crew class will need to copy Crew objects and assign one Crew object to another.

For parts a, b, and c below, you may implement additional Crew class helper functions if you like. Make no changes or additions to the Worker class.

a.

Complete the implementation of the destructor for the Crew class:

```
Crew::~Crew()
{
  for (int i=0; i<m_size; i++) {
    delete m_crew[i];
  }
}
```

b. Implement the copy constructor for the Crew class.

```
Crew::Crew(const Crew& original)
    : m_size(original.m_size), m_maxCrewSize(original.m_maxCrewSize)
{
  m_crew = new Worker*[m_maxCrewSize];
  for (int i=0; i < m_size; i++) {
    m_crew[i] = original.m_crew[i];
  } 
}
```

c. Implement the assignment operator for the Crew class.

```
Crew& Crew::operator=(const Crew& other) {
  if (this != &other) {
    Crew temp(*this);
    m_crew = other.m_crew;
    m_size = other.m_size;
    m_maxCrewSize = other.m_maxCrewSize;
    other.m_crew = temp.m_crew;
    other.m_maxCrewSize = temp.m_maxCrewSize;
    other.m_size = temp.m_size;
  }
  return this;
}
```

Comment: `The question is why they received only half-credit` - well, ask the person who supervised the exams and assigned scores. That's the perfect source of the answer. I know that's unhelpful and obvious, but really, with out the supervisor's point of view, that's mostly guesswork (of course except for some obvious bugs, if any, I didn't analyze the code - I'm just reacting to the original problem).

Comment: As explained in [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor): "If no user-defined constructors of any kind are provided for a class type ... the compiler will always declare a default constructor as an inline public member of its class." What that paragraph means is that if you have any custom constructor in a class, the default constructor is *not* generated.

Comment: Your destructor is incomplete.  Where is the `delete` for the m_crew pointer itself?  In other words, you failed to clean up the memory when you did this: `m_crew = new Worker*[lim];`

Comment: BTW. in the `operator=` if by `Crew temp(*this)` you wanted to make a "dry run" to check for any exceptions during the three partial assignments, then after the dry run, you should redo the assignments in the same order. If you are really making a dry-run, then changing the order of operations in the real run makes the dry-run results completely irrelevant. Also, their order looks strange. Usually you first check the max bound, then actual bound, then operate on items (but that's actually customary and case-specific)

Comment: Another FYI: makind such a dry-run for variables that are `Worker**` and `int` is completely unnecesary. Such assignments will never throw any errors. You can simplify the `operator=` to a simple three lines of `other...` wait, what?! You've messed up the implementation of it. The `operaotr=` should change into THIS and read from OTHER. So the last third assignments should be `this->m_crew = other.m_crew` and so on..

Comment: Also, if a deep copy is to be done in the copy constructor, all you should have done is call `hire` in a loop, using the data from the passed-in `Crew` reference.

Comment: "We choose to represent a crew as a dynamically allocated array of pointers to Workers" No we don't, that's a terrible idea - as evidenced by having to write all that code, and still getting it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1. The destructor does not deallocate the array of pointers, which means that it leaks.
2. The copy constructor does not perform a deep copy (which is probably expected)
3. The assignment operator is not only assigning values from `other` to `this`, but also from `this` to `other`. That's completely unexpected for an assignment operator, and it won't even compile because `other` is `const`.

Comment: Why the downvote? Alastair and I have independently come up with the same feedback.

Comment: about (1): note that the op= makes a shallow assignment of Workers**, so the ~dtor should not deallocate - noone assumed ownership. You covered it in (2) but why assumption about deep-copy requirement? It's perfectly ok to make shallow copies in some cases. Too many unexplained assumptions IMHO, and that could result in downvotes. However, assuming "typical" and "deep" all three points are valid. The last one is probably the most important, I've just noticed it too. Looks like an obvious typo and that could have been the cause of bad marks on the exam.

Comment: oh dear.. forget the 'ownership' thing.. I've just noticed the ctor/dtor pait that allocates the arrays and items.. what a mess

Answer (score 1):

While @quetzalcoatl is correct that you should ask whoever marked the question why they marked it that way, here are a few hints:

a. This answer fails to delete the `m_crew` array.  As a result, memory will leak.

b. In this answer, the workers themselves are not copied.  The program will crash when the destructor for either the new copy or the original `Crew` object runs, because of a double `delete`.

c. This answer is just plain wrong.  I have no idea why anyone would give half marks for it; I'd have given none.  First off, you can't write to `other` because it's `const`.  Second, you *shouldn't* write to `other` because the assignment operator is for assignment, *not* swapping.  Third, you can't just assign `m_crew` like that because it will cause a crash later on because of a double `delete`.

Comment: b. But isn't the copy constructor for the Worker class the default-generated one (as specified in the problem statement: Because we did not declare a destructor, copy constructor, or assignment operator for the Worker class, the compiler writes these functions for us.)...

Comment: @MattClarkson Or (better, IMO) `std::vector`.  However, this being an examination question, it’s best to stick to answers you think might be present in the mark scheme :-)

Comment: @JayYoon You aren't *copying* the `Worker` instances, though.  You’re merely copying *pointers* to them.  You’d need to write `new Worker(original.m_crew[i])` to actually copy them.

Comment: @alastair, completely agree. Just trying to point out that if someone in the future stubbles across this answer/question to not take the above as an example of modern C++ programming!